# Cursor comes back to center

Tags: windows-10, laptop, mouse-cursor, lid

Just a little background before I start the question: I have set the power management settings such that whenever I close the lid of my laptop, it won’t go to sleep and it works perfectly fine.

Now, the problem is whenever I close the lid and open it up after a while (no matter how short or long), the cursor returns back to the center of the screen and not where it was left before. I intend to change this such that the cursor stays where it was left off from before closing the lid.

Any possibility of changing this behavior, because notice that every time you log on after turning your machine on, the cursor is at the center.

Comment: Probably not. The mouse is part of logging on most times. I tried just now Suspending my laptop with the mouse positioned at the top left. When I opened the lid and used just keystrokes to log in, the mouse stayed put. Generally I do not close the lid unless suspending. I have seen laptop overheat if not suspended. I just position my mouse to where I need it when logging out.

Comment: @John :What do you mean by suspending the laptop, couldn’t understand your context.

Comment: If you Suspend (closing the lid Suspends if power properties have been properly set), the cursor will stay where it was if you do not use the mouse to log in.  If you change the power properties to run full tilt when you close the lid, the mouse will move to the log in screen as that is the first thing you need. So what you see without suspending is completely normal

Comment: @John :Also,does it work each and every time?

Comment: @John :Ok,but I want the cursor to be where it was after I open the lid.

Comment: If you are not suspending, the cursor moves to the log in bar. Normal operation, so you cannot do what you want. Suspending under full power generates heat, so I am at a loss why you do not suspend

Comment: @John :Actually I listen to songs with the lid closed and center my external mouse at the pause button, but it goes to the center and messes things up.

Comment: It may be better just to leave the lid open and then that will prevent messing up. I do not know another way.

Comment: @John :Well, it’s an OLed screen, so to reduce the chance of burning....

Comment: That is a good point. You can set your screen to go black after 5 minutes and then screen burning will not be an issue

Comment: @John : I am still not sure if it has turned off or not so I don’t wanna take risk.